# Nrf51822 programming for noobs

Tags: bluetooth, firmware, nrf51

I want to use a bluetoothmodul like this Waveshare Core51822 to send data to a raspberry. I want to use the SPI on the bluetooth modul but i dont have a plan how to configure that.

What do i need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SPI and BLE are all documented extensively at http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/, including examples, specifications, and an API.

In the future, you should give much more information about your situation.  For instance, what platform/IDE are you using to develop?  If your module is compatible, you would probably be best off using ARM's mbed compiler (https://os.mbed.com).